# passportJS authentication for all routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, middleware

I'm using passportJS for protecting API Endpoints in an Express APP.

The following is working fine.

```
app.get("/route1",
passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => { //something });
```

However, I'm adding more routes and don't want to repeat that `passport.authenticate` for every new route I create.

I.e.

```
 app.get("/route2..N",
    passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
        (req, res) => { //something });
```

I understand that this is a middleware and that I should be able to do this, but I haven't found any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`passport.authenticate` just returns a middleware function so:

```
app.use(passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false });
app.get("/route1", (req, res) => { /* something */ } )
```